# Seeding database with a one-to-many relationship in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Struggling to properly seed my database when my app starts up. `FlightId`, `DepartureAirportId`, `ArrivalAirportId`, `FlightDateTime` and `FlightDurationHours` all get added but how can I ensure the `Airport` column is added.

I have set-up a one to many relationship with Entity Framework between `Airport` and `Flights`.

The below code is inside my `AddDbInitializer` class which runs at start-up.

```
new Flight()
{
    DepartureAirportId = 3,
    ArrivalAirportId = 7,
    FlightDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 12, 21, 08, 0, 0, 0),
    FlightDurationHours = 2,
    Airport = context.Airports.Find(3) // ADDED THIS LINE BUT IT DOESN'T WORK
}
```

Flight class:

```
public class Flight
{
    public int FlightId { get; set; }
    public int DepartureAirportId { get; set; }
    public int ArrivalAirportId { get; set; }
    public DateTime FlightDateTime { get; set; }
    public int FlightDurationHours { get; set; }
    public Airport Airport { get; set; }
}
```

Airport class:

```
public class Airport
{
    public int AirportId { get; set; }
    public string AirportCode { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Flight> Flight { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you `context.SaveChanges()` after saving the airport?

You can add the data, but if you want to reference it for adding additional items, you need to commit it first otherwise it technically isn't there yet.

Comment: I did yeah, the airports are added just before it gets to where the flights are added.

Comment: Then your code is fine as long as there's an airport with `AirportId == 3`. Beyond that, you'll need to supply more info about what the problem is. Describe the behavior you're getting, error messages, etc.

Comment: Got to the bottom of it! Because I had deleted the entries from my database my `Airport` IDs had changed and were not starting from 1.

Comment: Would I be better configuring my `Flight` table so the `DepartureAirportId` and `ArrivalAirportId` are both actual Airport objects like `Airport` is? Is this even possible to have multiple Airport objects in one table when the relationship is one-to-many?

Answer (score 0):

Airport= context.Airports.Find(3) would be null That is not the correct way to use find method from LINQ. One way would be using lambda expression, change by context.Airports.find(x=>x.AirportId==3) Or you could the whole as a LINQ expression:
var airport=select a from context.Airports where a.AirportId==3;
new Filght(){
....
Aiport=airport
}